# How do I change build and target architectures for my GCC?

Tags: arch-linux, gcc

I know my linux box is x86_64 and I want to be able to compile FOR x86_64 as well via GCC. Currently...

```
gcc -v
```

shows

```
Using built-in specs.
**Target: i386-redhat-linux**
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info   
--enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-  
__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable- 
languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --enable-plugin  
--with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic **--host=i386-redhat-linux**
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
```

**How do I change the Target: to x86_64 and the --host to x86_64?**

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to upgrade my `gcc` to x86_64. I was running a x86_64 but for some reason my `gcc` was i386. I upgraded my `gcc` to 64bit by searching for it on yum and then tried updating. I had to delete the i386 `gcc` and some of its dependencies and then the update worked. `gcc -v` now shows Target: x86_64-redhat-linux